# passing std::function to javascript and calling it from javascript Emscripten

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, embind

Is there a way for me to pass an std::function<int(int, std::string)> from C++ to javascript and call with from JS with the appropriate int value?

I'm assuming this is possible with embind but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be a "std::function<int(int, std::string)>"? Why not just call a member function with the same signature?